# Connecting Storyboard and outlet doesnt work well in xcode 5.1, ios 7.1 sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I try sometimes to connect label or button to its outlet in the class, but xcode doesnt accept the connection.

As in this picture, i cannot connect the label in the sotryboard to the outlet label resultLabel.

[image]

Comment: You see how you picked the header file manually? (Manual > ... > JSONViewController.h). It should appear automatically. You probably haven't specified in the StoryBoard that the ViewController you are editing by drag and dropping views on it, is actually an instance of JSONViewController.

Comment: it didnt appear automatically..so that i tried to connect it manually

Comment: Exactly, because you most likely haven't set the class of the view controller in the inspector side bar.

Comment: you are right, it is exactly the reason why i couldnt connect them

Comment: I make this mistake over and over. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your viewController in Storyboard is connected to your class.

Click on the yellow button:
[image: Click on the yellow button]

Choose identity inspector tab and enter your class's name:

[image]

Comment: @MBH: so you may want to accept this to let other know that the question is answered :)

Answer (score 1):

To create IBOutlets and IBActions to ViewControllers you must first set the File Owner to that ViewController in StoryBoard or Nib.

I have encountered this bug in Xcode 6. If it happens just clear file owner clean project and set File owner again to the same view controller.